# Show that $\frac{(x^2 + y^2 )}{4} \leq e^{x+y-2}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Show that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2 + y^2}{4} \leq e^{x+y-2}
\end{equation}
is true for $x,y \geq 0$.

As far, I have prove that 
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 \leq e^{x}e^{y}\leq e^{x+y}
\end{equation}
since $e^{x}\geq x^2$ and $e^{y}\geq y^2$. If someone can give some aid it would be nice!

Comment: Switch to polar coordinates, it will all become clear to you in an instant.

Comment: I am not clear on how you obtained the inequality: $x^2 + y^2 < e^{x} e^{y}$ from $e^{x} \ge x^2$ and $e^y \ge y^2$. It seems to me that you would end up with $$x^2 + y^2 \le e^x + e^y.$$

Comment: @Joel Since $ e^{x} \geq x^2 \geq 0$ and  $ e^{y} \geq y^2 \geq 0$ , multiplying $e^{x}e^{y} \geq x^2 y^2 \geq x^2+y^2$. Although his work form $y,x\geq 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use that $e^t\geq 1+t$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x+y\geq 0$: $$e^{x+y-2}=\left(e^{\frac{x+y}{2}-1}\right)^2\geq\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

To sketch it out  :

Let $x = r\cos\theta $ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Upon considering both $x$, $y$ are  $\geq 0$ we get $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $r>0$. Plug in the substitutions into your initial inequality to get $\frac{e^2r^2}{4} \leq e^{r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}$ .

Now, on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ we get (pretty intuitively) that $\min(\sin\theta +\cos\theta) = 1$. Use this fact, along with a truncated version of the Taylor expansion for $e^x$ to complete your proof.

Comment: Did you want to write $\frac{r^2}{4}$ in the place where you have $\frac{e^2r^2}{4}$? The substitution gives $x^2+y^2=r^2$, i.e., $\frac{x^2+y^2}4=\frac{r^2}4$.

Comment: Well, I got $e^{r(cos\theta+sin\theta)-2}$ considering the initial equation , hence the $e^2$

Comment: I completely missed that. Thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem, thanks for asking !